# return no errors on command line syntax

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If you run `rm -r /var/some/dir/*` and the dir is empty an error is returned

How can you supress this error so its not returned?

I use it in a linux bash script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from redirecting to stderr, you can also use `-f`:

```
rm -rf /var/some/dir/*
```

From `man rm`:

```
-f, --force
            ignore nonexistent files and arguments, never prompt
```

Answer (score 2):

Redirect stderr:

```
rm -r /var/some/dir/* 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you question mentions **[if] dir is empty an error is returned** (so assuming the directory exists), that's because the glob `/var/some/dir/*` matches nothing, hence bash (with the default unset `nullglob` and `failglob`) will pass the string `/var/some/dir/*` verbatim. And there are no such files, so `rm` complains.

Since you're using this in a bash script, I would advise you to proceed as follows:

```bash
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -u failglob
declare -a files=( /var/some/dir/* )
if (( ${#files[@]} )); then
    rm -r -- "${files[@]}" # || error handling
fi
```

- The `shopt -s nullglob` will make globs expand to nothing if no matching files exist,
- You put the matching files in an array `files` (and because `nullglob` is set, the array `files` is empty if there are no matches),
- *If* there are matching files, then `rm` them.

Proceeding like this will make your script more robust, as you'll be able to catch a genuine error occuring in `rm` (with the `|| error handling` part) and not confuse this with an error occurring from a non-matched glob.

Doing so, you will not launch a random command with uncontrolled arguments.

**Remark.** It is not quite true that the error you obtain occurs only when the directory is empty. It occurs when the directory contains no files, except possibly hidden files. If you want to really purge the directory from also potential hidden files, you must `shopt -s dotglob` so that the glob will also match hidden files.